# C#, filtering IEnumerable with multiple .Where() statements, performance hits

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable, and I'm applying multiple filters to it via .Where expression. My code looks something like this

```
public List<MyObject> FilteringFunction(List<MyObject> listToFilter, List<Filter> filters)
{
    // A dirty way to have an enumerable instead of List
    var enumerableToFilter = listToFilter.Where(x => true);

    foeach(var filter in filters)
    {
        enumerableToFilter = enumerableToFilter.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(filter.Value));
    }

    return enumerableToFilter.ToList();

}
```

Am I going to iterate through my collection only once? (As I would have only one database call with LINQ to SQL)

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense... if you have filters with different values, the filtered result will always be empty

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Unless you've overridden the `==` such that unequal objects return `true`.  (Not that that makes it a sensible thing to be doing.)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque,  sorry, I was simplifying real code to make it more readable and over simplified it. Actual where statements are not simple == , but more complicated. I will correct my question and make it .Contains(), for example.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque in real code there are different kinds of filters (equals,  contains, startwith, greater, smaller, etc) applied to different fields of MyObject

Comment: By the way, a less dirty way to turn a list into an IEnumerable is with the `.AsEnumerable()` extension method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumerables defer execution until you iterate over them, and multiple filters are applied on a single iteration through the collection. Combining with other linq statements may force early enumeration, I haven't tested every combination. This would only be a problem with very large data sets or on low spec performance critical systems.

Here is an example using Visual Studios c# interactive

```
> class Item
. {
.     private int _number;
.     public int Number
.     {
.         get { Console.WriteLine($"Got number {_number}"); return _number; }
.         set { _number = value; }
.     }
. }
> 
> IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>() { 
.     new Item { Number = 1 },
.     new Item { Number = 2 },
.     new Item { Number = 3 },
.     new Item { Number = 4 },
.     new Item { Number = 5 },
.     new Item { Number = 6 }
. };
> 
> var filteredItems = items.Where(item => item.Number > 3).Where(item => item.Number % 2 == 0);
> 
> var listedItems = filteredItems.ToList();
Got number 1
Got number 2
Got number 3
Got number 4
Got number 4
Got number 5
Got number 5
Got number 6
Got number 6
>
```

Note that 1, 2, and 3 are filtered out and the second filter method is not called on them. 4, 5, and 6 all pass the first filter so both filters are applied.

**Key Point:** Note that the filtering doesn't actually happen until the enumerable is read to a list. You will be able to continue appending filters until you enumerate the result to a list.

Comment: That is information I was looking for. Thank you Kelson Ball and @David L

Answer (score 1):

First  of all the result will be empty for sure sine your filtering  the same property with the different values, and let say you corrected this, answering on your question, for iqueryable it will call the database just once, for Enumerable object  is the same ,  as the iteration will happen just when you  iterate the object with foreach or calling GetEnumerator , in your case you are not doing that

Answer (score 0):

The overhead could become noticeable if you have many filters, due to the many delegate creations and invocations and many calls to `Where`. That being said, you should probably run performance tests to determine if it's really an issue.

You could refactor the code to test all the filters in the same predicate:

```
public List<MyObject> FilteringFunction(List<MyObject> listToFilter, List<Filter> filters)
{
    Func<MyObject, bool> predicate =
        x =>
            filters.All(f => x.Value.Contains(f.Value));

    return listToFilter.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

---

PS: regarding this:

```
// A dirty way to have an enumerable instead of List
```

There's a cleaner way:

```
var enumerableToFilter = listToFilter as IEnumerable<MyObject>;
```

or even:

```
var enumerableToFilter = listToFilter.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if my filters are more complex then simple .Contains? I have many kinds of filters  (equals, contains, startwith, greater, smaller, etc) applied to different fields of MyObject

Comment: And I have no idea who would give a downvote for such a great answer.

Comment: @Anarion, maybe you should refactor your code so that filters have a `bool Match(MyObject x)` abstract method. This way, you can just implement the method differently based on the type of filter, and use the abstraction from the call site.

Comment: Thanks! If I do it that way - will I have only one iteration through my collection?

Comment: @Anarion yes (but the filters will be enumerated as many times as there are items)

Comment: btw, even your original code was iterating through the collection only once, because of deferred execution. I believe the implementation I suggested will be faster, though, because it has less overhead. But you should run perf tests to make sure.